# How to check if a set1 is a subset of set2 in Scheme?

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, subset, racket

I tried to write a code to return 'true' if set1 is a subset of set2.

for example: (subset '(a b) '(a c b d)) --> #t  (subset '(a b) '(a c d)) --> #f

Here's what I did, can someone enlighten me why isn't it working?

```
(define (subset lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst2) #f)
        ((member (car lst1)  lst2)
         (subset  (cdr lst1)  lst2)
         #t)
        (else #f)))
```

Comment: `(subset '() '())`, should be true, no? And your second clause is always `#t`.(Why the `#t`?)

Comment: yeah you are right, it should check if both sets are empty and return true. Also, I put the #t because I want it to return true if the element in the first set do exist in the second set else it returns #f

Comment: Probably won't be accepted if this is for a class, but you can load SRFI-1 and use `(lset<= eq? lst1 lst2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ((member (car lst1) lst2)
     (subset (cdr lst1) lst2) 
     #t)
```

`true` has no reason there.  You reduce the problem to a subproblem.

Also, no need to check `(null? lst2)`, as you do not loop over lst2.  The final condition must check `lst1` instead.

I would write so:

```
(define (subset lst1 lst2)
  (or (null? lst1)
      (and (member (car lst1) lst2)
           (subset (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
```